# Где необходимо хранить изображения в asp.net приложениях?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Мне нужно где-то хранить аватары пользователей. Где это лучше делать? У меня есть три варианта:

1. Хранить массив byte в базе данных. В представлении будет код на подобие такого: 
   `<img style='width:80px; height:60px; src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(p.Avatar))" />`
2. Хранить jpg файлы в папке со статическими файлами проекта.

Comment: В базе - плохо. Негоже бинарные данные в базу складывать. Файлы на диск, в базе ссылки только.

Comment: И так, и так можно. Кроме того, в ряде СУБД есть специальные средства для хранения бинарных данных. Например, [FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) в SqlServer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранить картинки в БД не лучшая практика, тк возрастает число запросов к БД, так же увеличивается вес БД. Постоянное кодирование и декодирование картинок создает нагрузку. Плюсом этого способа является безопасность.

В большинстве случаев хранить пути картинок в БД лучше.